# Trouble setting up Jinq with Play Framework

Tags: java, spring, jpa, playframework

I am using the **play-spring-data-jpa** template and have added Jinq. As per the [Jinq official documentation](http://www.jinq.org/docs/spring.html#N65622) I have followed the steps to *initialize Jinq as a Singleton Bean*. However as there is no **application-context.xml** file I have nowhere to add

```
<bean id="jinq" class="com.example.JinqSource"/>
```

or the Play equivalent.

**My stack trace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant: 18
     scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$.getConstant(Parser.scala:150)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$.parse$1(Parser.scala:127)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$.sbt$classfile$Parser$$parseConstantPool(Parser.scala:132)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$$anon$1.<init>(Parser.scala:32)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$.parseImpl(Parser.scala:24)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$.sbt$classfile$Parser$$parse(Parser.scala:20)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Parser.scala:19)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Parser.scala:19)
     sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
     sbt.classfile.Parser$.apply(Parser.scala:19)
     sbt.classfile.Analyze$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Analyze.scala:32)
     sbt.classfile.Analyze$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Analyze.scala:31)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
     scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
     scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
     sbt.classfile.Analyze$.apply(Analyze.scala:31)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:138)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
     scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
     scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:159)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileJava$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:135)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:142)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:86)
     sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:38)
     sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:36)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:73)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:33)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:32)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:41)
     sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:32)
     sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:26)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:150)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:70)
     sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:45)
     sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:70)
     sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:722)
     sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:716)
     sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:716)
     scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
     sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
     sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
     sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
     sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
     sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
     sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
     sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Play framework, but it seems like it might let you use [JSR330 annotations for dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Singletons) instead of whatever Spring uses. So I guess maybe you can just label the JinqSource as being a @Singleton, and the Play framework will be able to wire things up properly for you, maybe?

The stack trace you are getting seems to be a [problem with using old versions of Scala's sbt with Java 8](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/842). You should upgrade to a newer version of the Scala tools.

If you are trying to use Jinq with Scala, you should use Jinq for Scala JPA instead of the normal Jinq stuff since it contains support for Scala lists and lambdas.